# regexp to parse a mysql orderby string

Tags: php, preg-replace

I could have these strings:

1. "volume asc, edition desc"
2. "volume ASC, othercolumn desc, columnx DESC"

I want obtain arrays like these:

1. array( 'volume', 'asc', 'edition', 'desc' );
2. array( 'volume', 'asc', 'othercolumn', 'desc', 'columnx', 'desc' );

How to reach that with regexp/preg_match functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$arr = array(
    "volume asc, edition desc",
    "volume ASC, othercolumn desc, columnx DESC"
);
foreach($arr as $str) {
    $res = preg_split('/[ ,]+/', $str);
    print_r($res);
}
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => volume
    [1] => asc
    [2] => edition
    [3] => desc
)
Array
(
    [0] => volume
    [1] => ASC
    [2] => othercolumn
    [3] => desc
    [4] => columnx
    [5] => DESC
)
```

Comment: This and, as stated by @vaichidrewar in his answer, he could use `strtolower` to convert all to lowercase. It could be called this way: `array_walk('strtolower', $res)`

Answer (score 1):

It'd be a better approach to use a parse such as [PHP SQL Parser](http://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser/).

Answer (score -1):

```
$str = 'volume asc, edition desc';
$chars = preg_split('/ /', $str);
print_r($chars);

Array ( [0] => volume [1] => asc, [2] => edition [3] => desc )
```

You can convert each string to lowercase using strtolower function